# Where to get the MWE2 libraries

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, mwe

I'm trying to get a MWE2 workflow running programmatically. When Eclipse provides the dependencies, this all works fine, and I can get the `new Mwe2Launcher().run();` call to work.

However, when I'm running outside of Eclipse, I don't know from which Maven repo to get the jars I have to depend on. I've tried getting them from `http://build.eclipse.org/common` (tried `http://build.eclipse.org/common/xtend/maven` and `http://build.eclipse.org/common/xtext/maven/maven-snapshot/final` as repo locations, but they aren't there.
As far as I know, I need (at least) the `org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core` (1.2.1, perhaps 1.3.0?) and `org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch` (2.4.0?) jars.

Does anyone know in which Maven repo Eclipse provides these dependencies? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't provide maven artifacts in general, because most project's rely on OSGi and p2. The Xtext project, which maintains MWE hasn't yet uploaded the jars to any maven repository. You can find a slightly older version here :

https://www.fornax-platform.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/eclipse/plugins/

Not sure if it works for you, there hasn't been too many updates in MWE2 since then.